# Mysql replication from two masters

Tags: mysql, replication

Here's my mysql cluster setup

All nodes have a database db with following tables

`table1`
`table2`
`table3`

`NODE1` gets `table2` from `NODE2`, `table3` FROM `NODE3`

`NODE2` gets `table1` from `NODE1`

`NODE3` gets `table1` from `NODE1`

Is this possible with mysql replication?

Comment: I know that we can exclude or include some tables/databases in mysql replication and also that a master can also be a slave. The only problem is `Can a slave have multiple masters?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its not possible with a normal master/slave replication. For this you need something like the [mysql cluster](http://www.mysql.de/products/cluster/) version.

The main problem is the [master / master](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication) replication without the cluster. Then you get some trouble with IDs and something else. I have tried this before a lot of time. And when you write on both master and one master is before the other and will write to the other and the primary key exists and you cannot write its very strange.

I have put a link to HowToForge there is an article to set up a master / master replication you can try it.

Perhaps you can look for alternatives like couchedb or mongodb its no mysql but with the nosql databases you can better replicate and scale.